# Selected Card via Picker is not displaying data

Tags: c#, maui

**What I'm trying to do:**
API retrieves an array of cards. However, only 1 is displayed. The user chooses whichever card he wants to use via a Picker. After selecting a card, the card data is displayed (Card Number, Valid Month and Year, etc.)

**What is happening:**
Picker is getting populated with the data from the API. After selecting a card, no data is displayed.

**Things that I have checked:**
Feedback is that the code is fine. Visual Studio is not reporting any data binding errors. Debugging runs fine, no exceptions, no nothing. API is running and data is being retrieved.

***MenuPage.xaml***

```
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BankingApp"
             xmlns:res="clr-namespace:BankingApp.Resources"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             x:Class="BankingApp.MenuPage"
             Title="MenuPage"
             BackgroundColor="#041014"
             Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False" NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False">
    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout>

            <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="0,20,0,20" Text="{x:Static res:LanguageResources.YourAccount}" FontSize="32"/>
        
        <!--Account Bank Card-->    
            <Grid Margin="25,0,25,0" >
                <!--<Image Source="bankcardesb.svg" Aspect="AspectFill"/>-->
                <StackLayout x:Name="selectedCardLayout"
                 IsVisible="{Binding IsCardSelected}">
                    <Label Text="{Binding SelectedCard.card_number}"
               FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                    <Label Text="{Binding SelectedCard.card_type}" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding SelectedCard.valid_month}"/>
                </StackLayout>
                <Frame>
                    <Label x:Name="balanceLabel"  FontSize="Medium" />
                </Frame>
            </Grid>
            
            <Picker x:Name="CardPicker"
                    Margin="0,0,20,20"
                    BackgroundColor="#5fb3f9"
                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                     HeightRequest="50"
                    WidthRequest="150"
                    HorizontalOptions="End"
           SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCard}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Cards}"
          SelectedIndex="0"
          ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding card_number}" />
           
        <Button HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="10" WidthRequest="200" HeightRequest="50" BackgroundColor="#00B2FF"
                    Text="{x:Static res:LanguageResources.MakeTransaction}" TextColor="White" FontFamily="AgeoBold" FontSize="18" Clicked="GotoTransactionPage"/>
         
        <Button HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="10" WidthRequest="200" HeightRequest="50" BackgroundColor="#00B2FF"
                    Text="{x:Static res:LanguageResources.GoToLoans}" TextColor="White" FontFamily="AgeoBold" FontSize="18" Clicked="GotoLoanPage"/>

        <!--TransactionList-->
            <StackLayout Margin="50,10,50,0" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Transactions}">
                <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <toolkit:Expander BackgroundColor="#5fb3f9" Margin="0,0,0,5" Padding="10">
                            <toolkit:Expander.Header>
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Label FontFamily="OpenSansSemibold" Text="{Binding date_time}" FontSize="Small" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
                                    <Label FontFamily="OpenSansSemibold" Text="{Binding amount}" FontSize="Small" HorizontalOptions="End" />
                                    <Label FontFamily="OpenSansSemibold" Text="{Binding currency}" FontSize="Small" HorizontalOptions="End" />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </toolkit:Expander.Header>
                            <StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding IsExpanded}">
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Label FontFamily="AgeoBold" Text="{x:Static res:LanguageResources.RecipientName} " FontSize="Small" />
                                    <Label Text="{Binding name_recipient}" FontSize="Small" />
                                </StackLayout>
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" >
                                    <Label FontFamily="AgeoBold" Text="{x:Static res:LanguageResources.IBANPayer}" FontSize="Small" />
                                    <Label Text="{Binding iban_payer}" FontSize="Small" />
                                </StackLayout>
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" >
                                    <Label FontFamily="AgeoBold" Text="{x:Static res:LanguageResources.IBANRecipient}" FontSize="Small" />
                                    <Label Text="{Binding iban_recipient}" FontSize="Small" />
                                </StackLayout>
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Label FontFamily="AgeoBold" Text="{x:Static res:LanguageResources.PaymentDescription}" FontSize="Small" />
                                    <Label Text="{Binding payment_description}" FontSize="Small" />
                                </StackLayout>
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" >
                                    <Label FontFamily="AgeoBold" Text="{x:Static res:LanguageResources.ReferenceNumber}" FontSize="Small" />
                                    <Label Text="{Binding reference_number}" FontSize="Small" />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </toolkit:Expander>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
            </StackLayout>
            
    </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

***MenuPage.xaml.cs***

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net.Http;
using BankingApp.Models;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls;
using BankingApp.Services;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Xml;
using BankingApp.Views;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace BankingApp
{
    public partial class MenuPage : ContentPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
       //Transactions
        private ObservableCollection<TransactionData> _transactions = new ObservableCollection<TransactionData>();
        public ObservableCollection<TransactionData> Transactions
        {
            get { return _transactions; }
            set
            {
                _transactions = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Transactions));
            }
        }

        //Cards
        private ObservableCollection<CardData> _cards = new ObservableCollection<CardData>();
        public ObservableCollection<CardData> Cards
        {
            get { return _cards; }
            set
            {
                _cards = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Cards));
            }
        }
        //Selected Card
        private CardData _selectedCard;
        public CardData SelectedCard
        {
            get { return _selectedCard; }
            set { _selectedCard = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedCard)); OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsCardSelected)); }
        }
        public bool IsCardSelected
        {
            get { return SelectedCard != null; }
        }

        //Active Account
        public Account SelectedAccount { get; }
        
        //Account Balance
        public class AccountBalance
        {

            [JsonProperty("status")]
            public string status { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("msg")]
            public string msg { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("data")]
            public string data { get; set; }

            
        }
        public MenuPage(Account _selectedAccount)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Title = "Transactions";
            BindingContext = this;
            SelectedAccount = _selectedAccount;
        }

        //When the screen appears
        protected override async void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            await GetTransactionsAsync();
            await GetBalanceAsync();
            await GetCardsAsync();
        }

        //Confirm you want to go back
        protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
        {
            MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => {
                var result = await this.DisplayAlert("Alert!", "Do you really want to choose another account?", "Yes", "No");
                if (result) await this.Navigation.PopAsync(); 
            });

            return true;
        }

        //Get Transactions from Account
        private async Task GetTransactionsAsync()
        {
            string iban = App.ActiveAccount.iban;
            string url = $"https://example";

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                TransactionsResponse responseObj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TransactionsResponse>(json);
                Transactions = responseObj.data;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Error: Unable to get transactions data.");
            }
        }

        //Get Account Balance
        private async Task GetBalanceAsync()
        {
            string iban = App.ActiveAccount.iban;
            string url = $"https://example";

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();              

                JObject resultX = JObject.Parse(responseString);
                JObject data = (JObject)resultX["data"];
                string account_balance = (string)data["account_balance"];
                balanceLabel.Text = account_balance + "€";

            }
            else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Error: Unable to get balance data.");
            }
        }

        //Get Client Cards

        private async Task GetCardsAsync()
        {
            int id_client = App.ActiveAccount.id_client_account;
            string url = $"https://example";

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                CardsResponse responseObj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CardsResponse>(json);
                Cards = responseObj.data;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Error: Unable to get Card data.");
            }
        }


        //More Transactions -> Updates
        public new event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected override void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);

            if (propertyName == "Transactions")
            {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Transactions"));
            }
            else
            {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        public class TransactionsResponse
        {
            public ObservableCollection<TransactionData> data { get; set; }

        }

        public class CardsResponse
        {
            public ObservableCollection<CardData> data { get; set; }

        }
        private void GotoTransactionPage(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Navigation.PushAsync(new MakeTransactionPage());
        }
        private void GotoLoanPage(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Navigation.PushAsync(new LoansPage(SelectedAccount));
        }
    }
}
```

***GetCards.cs***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BankingApp.Services
{
    public class CardData
      {
        [JsonProperty("id_client_account")]
        public string id_client_account { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("card_number")]
        public string card_number { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("valid_month")]
        public int valid_month { get; set; }
        
        [JsonProperty("valid_year")]
        public int valid_year { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("card_type")]
        public string card_type { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you debugged the setter of `SelectedCard`?

Comment: `Selected Card` is returning the value of the card which was selected. `IsCardSelected` returning true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Grid Margin="25,0,25,0" >    
    <StackLayout x:Name="selectedCardLayout">
        <Label Text="{Binding SelectedCard.card_number}">
        ......
    </StackLayout>
    <Frame >
        <Label x:Name="balanceLabel"  FontSize="Medium" />
    </Frame>
</Grid>
```

According to your code above, in the **Grid** layout, the **Frame** shelters the **StackLayout**. So you cannot see the data. You could set the RowDefinition [RowDefinition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/grid#rows-and-columns) and  [ColumnDefinition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/grid#rows-and-columns) to arrange the children in Grid layout or use other layout.

Also, there is an issue about SelectedIndex for Picker now : [Picker SelectedIndex property not working](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/7138). A workaround is to set SelectedIndex in the code behind instead of xaml:

```
public MainPage()
{      
    InitializeComponent();
    ...
    CardPicker.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

For more info, you could refer to [Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/grid)

Hope it works.